# Can I create method inside the fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am kind of new to android studio thing. I got some questions to ask. How do I add method locally in fragments and how can I show it in app? I am trying to show my data from existing database with REST API using Retrofit, to show it in Android fragment. I tried different tutorials from YouTube but I am not sure with it.

This is the code for RecyclerView Adapter:

```
    package com.example.cyberview_android1;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerHolder> {

    List<ProfileModel> models;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ProfileModel> models) {
        this.models = models;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {

        recyclerHolder.textView.setText(models.get(i).profile_cat);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public RecyclerHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for Fragment:

```
package com.example.cyberview_android1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView rvProfile;


    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rvProfile = rvProfile.findViewById(R.id.rv_profile);
        rvProfile.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ProfileFragment.this));
        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<List<ProfileModel>> listCall = retrofitInterface.getAllProfile();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProfileModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ProfileModel>> call, Response<List<ProfileModel>> response) {
                parseData(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ProfileModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    }

    private void parseData(List<ProfileModel> body) {
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(body);
        rvProfile.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }
}package com.example.cyberview_android1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView rvProfile;


    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rvProfile = rvProfile.findViewById(R.id.rv_profile);
        rvProfile.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ProfileFragment.this));
        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<List<ProfileModel>> listCall = retrofitInterface.getAllProfile();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProfileModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ProfileModel>> call, Response<List<ProfileModel>> response) {
                parseData(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ProfileModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    }

    private void parseData(List<ProfileModel> body) {
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(body);
        rvProfile.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is the retrofit instance code:

```
package com.example.cyberview_android1;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

The interface:

```
package com.example.cyberview_android1;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("/employee/profile")
    Call<List<ProfileModel>> getAllProfile();


}
```

And the model:

```
package com.example.cyberview_android1;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ProfileModel {

    @SerializedName("category")
    String profile_cat;

    @SerializedName("description")
    String profile_desc;

    @SerializedName("date")
    String date;

    public String getProfile_cat() {
        return profile_cat;
    }

    public void setProfile_cat(String profile_cat) {
        this.profile_cat = profile_cat;
    }

    public String getProfile_desc() {
        return profile_desc;
    }

    public void setProfile_desc(String profile_desc) {
        this.profile_desc = profile_desc;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I am getting an error from the Holders and View groups. I followed the steps from the tutorial but I assure that I didnt miss anything from it.

[image]

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change viewGroup with parent
And recyclerHolder with holder

And your error will go away

Comment: Change `get(i)` with `get(position)`

Answer (score 0):

Mortuza is right. You can change your code like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(models.get(position).profile_cat);
}
```

For second error you can use context. If you want to get context from fragment you can use getActivity() or requireActivity().

Remove this line:

```
rvProfile.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ProfileFragment.this));
```

And then add this line:

```
rvProfile.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Comment: I also got rvProfile.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ProfileFragment.this)); as error. It says ProfileFragment cannot be converted to context. how do I resolve this? I searched other answers but i dont get it

Comment: ProfileFragment.this cannot be converted to context

Comment: you must give the context of your activity to it , to do so use getActivity() instead of ProfileFragment.this

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, viewGroup, false);
```

to:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_customer_customlist , parent , false);
```

and:

```
recyclerHolder.textView.setText(models.get(position).profile_cat);
```

to:

```
holder.textView.setText(models.get(position).profile_cat);
```

this would solve your problem but if you want to know what exactly does adapters do I have a brief explain for you:

adapters usually have 4 main parts :

1- onCreateViewHolder
2- A ViewHolder sub_class
3- onBindViewHolder
4- getItemCount

1-in onCreateViewHolder you will set your viewHolder xml view and then return a ViewHolder object.(this is where you create an instance of your itemView)
(you have two arguments here a ViewGroup and a viewType )
ViewGroup is the parent view of your itemView it means the parent of your xml layout file that you inflate in this method to create a view Object :

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, viewGroup, false);
```

viewtype is for implementing multiple viewTypes in your recycler and is not necessary in your scenario so I just skip it.

2-in your viewHolder class you can get access to your itemView widgets.

3-in onBindViewHolder which will be called when you scroll or a dataset change by notifying the adapter, data will be set based on your model by its position

4-getItemCount will identify the size of your items in the adapter.(in your scenario it's models):

```
List<ProfileModel> models;
```